# Permission using chmod in macOS

Tags: macos, chmod

Im trying to get access to permission using  `chmod -R 777 /Users/../example.txt`
on my macOS Catalina. Command work, but nothing is changing. The permission is still remains the same
How I can get "777" permission?
Thanks

Comment: If `..` is not you then you don't have permission to change it

Comment: following on vadian's comment, if you really want to `chmod` that path as written, you'd need to attempt `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/../example.txt`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask about this. Also, it'd help to provide more information, like the actual path (some directories have special security restrictions on them), and the file's permissions, flags, etc (use the output of `ls -leO@ /Users/../example.txt`) before & after running `chmod`. Finally, why are you trying to set the mode to 777? That's almost never what you actually want.

Comment: Coming from a multiuser Unix world,  never set permissions to 777.  Doesn't the path `/Users/../example.txt` resolve to `/example.txt` why is this file in the root directory.  Have you tried using `sudo` ?  And doesn't Catalina require additional permissions?